# Character encoding O&#x27

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, encoding, character-encoding

I'm getting the following from a data source

```
O&#x27;Brien
```

It should be rendered as

```
O'Brien
```

How can encode/transform this string as what it is supposed to be?

Also, how is this kind of encoding called?

Comment: It's called an HTML entity. If you assign it to `innerHTML` it will be rendered as expected.

Comment: @Barmar I'm trying to do this in `node` do you know how can I achieve it?

Comment: It is just an hex code of the character, between `&x` and `;`. You can just write a function to do the translation.